# I want to join my Ex Employer....Need suggestions

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, job-change

I left my old company after working for 5.5 years and I was happy with my work and pay package there.Eventually, I joined a new firm three months back as my ex manager offered me a good position with a handsome salary. But soon after joining I realized that the work environment here was not good and It was really stressful job and I wasn't able to enjoy my social life as I was made to handle multiple tasks with unrealistic deadlines. 
After completing three months I resigned and now I am planning to join my Ex employer and already spoken to the manager over there.

My question is how would i manage issues relating to people pointing at me, thinking that I came back here and I am not eligible or talented enough to find a position in any other firm.

Need suggestions from you people or Anyone had the same experience can share their views.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you really resign before you had a new job lined up?

Comment: Why do you care what other people think?  Who cares what the others think about your abilities, as long as the bosses know what you can do, no one else matters.

Comment: You may want to change the post title, as that one-letter difference changes the meaning considerably.

Comment: That stigma may exist initially, but just keep being you and before you know it the situation will be old news and things will go back to normal. To elaborate, initially people might have developed the perception that you aren't going to stick around for long because you're chasing the next best thing, but as each week goes by and you're still there that perception will only weaken until it no longer exists.

Answer (score 9):

> My question is how would i manage issues relating to people pointing at me, thinking that I came back here and I am not eligible or talented enough to find a position in any other firm.

Don't.

First of all, they're probably not doing that. Why do you think they're doing that? You *did* find a position in another firm. You were in fact poached for it. You didn't like it. End of story. Nobody else's business.

Even if they are, well, you'll just have to deal with it. The fact of the matter is that you changed your mind, and people change their minds all the time. Either your old employer will be happy to have you back or they won't, but this will be indicated in whether they extend you an employment offer or not.

Going into it worrying more about water-cooler chit-chat about your potential is folly; show that you are eligible and talented enough by working with them professionally and effectively, and nothing else will matter.

FWIW, one of my colleagues is on his second period of employment here, in a completely different role to the one he had to begin with (which had been filled by someone else in the interim), and nobody's ever thought less of him for it.

Answer (score 6):

Happens.

Here we have the same guy arriving... for the 3rd time in 5 years. HR is the target of jokes, not him.

19 years ago, I saw another case. The production engineer did leave the mill for a job near his family, didn't meet its objectives at the new job, and his replacement was subpar. Was back after one year. Was expected as the messiah.

It's uncommon, but it happens. That's one of the reasons you shall NEVER burn bridges while leaving(sounds like you did not). You were not careful resigning before having a steady job, but I don't see anything else suspicious.

In both case, the only important thing to do for them was not to show off. They're back because they had problems elsewhere, not at home. So it's not a big problem.